# Instances in AWS VPC cannot reach internet via VPN

Tags: amazon-web-services, networking, amazon-vpc

I am trying to setup an AWS VPC to host EC2 instances that will appear on my local network. Connection is via an IPsec site-to-site VPN. Everything works fine except my instances cannot connect to the internet.

What I have setup is the same as the following diagram from the AWS docs:

[Site-to-Site VPN example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d1RTT.png)

But I would like the instances within the VPC to access the internet and do it via the VPN connection and my gateway (not an AWS Internet Gateway or NAT Gateway). Perhaps this simply isn't possible?

The route table for the VPC looks like this:

[Route table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xCDRR.png)

vgw-0591... is the virtual private gateway connected via VPN to my gateway so I was trying to route internet traffic there, but clearly it's not doing what I'd hoped.

To show what's working I can create an instance in the private subnet in the VPC and SSH into it from a local machine:

```
local-machine$ ssh -i keypair.pem ubuntu@10.255.0.223
Welcome to Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS (GNU/Linux 4.15.0-1065-aws x86_64)

 * Documentation:  https://help.ubuntu.com
 * Management:     https://landscape.canonical.com
 * Support:        https://ubuntu.com/advantage
[...]
```

Then this machine can ping back to the local network via the VPN and my gateway (router):

```
ubuntu@ip-10-255-0-223:~$ ping 192.168.1.211
PING 192.168.1.211 (192.168.1.211) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 192.168.1.211: icmp_seq=1 ttl=63 time=29.1 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.1.211: icmp_seq=2 ttl=63 time=28.3 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.1.211: icmp_seq=3 ttl=63 time=29.6 ms
^C
--- 192.168.1.211 ping statistics ---
3 packets transmitted, 3 received, 0% packet loss, time 2003ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 28.396/29.068/29.652/0.516 ms
```

But the instance cannot connect to the internet:

```
ubuntu@ip-10-255-0-223:~$ ping www.google.com
PING www.google.com (74.125.193.147) 56(84) bytes of data.
^C
--- www.google.com ping statistics ---
3 packets transmitted, 0 received, 100% packet loss, time 2027ms
```

I'm not sure how to interpret the tracepath output either:

```
ubuntu@ip-10-255-0-223:~$ tracepath www.google.com
 1?: [LOCALHOST]                      pmtu 9001
 1:  ip-10-255-0-1.eu-west-1.compute.internal              0.156ms pmtu 1500
 1:  no reply
 2:  no reply
^C
ubuntu@ip-10-255-0-223:~$ tracepath 192.168.1.211
 1?: [LOCALHOST]                      pmtu 9001
 1:  ip-10-255-0-1.eu-west-1.compute.internal              0.173ms pmtu 1500
 1:  ???                                                   0.273ms pmtu 1422
 1:  no reply
 2:  ip-192-168-1-211.eu-west-1.compute.internal          32.605ms reached
     Resume: pmtu 1422 hops 2 back 2
```

Comment: How do your route tables look in the VPC?

Comment: Is the instance in a private subnet? If so, did you create a NAT gateway and associated route table entries? Is the NAT gateway properly attached to an internet gateway?

Comment: Are you saying that your instances are in a private VPC and you would like them to access the Internet by traversing the VPN connection back to your own network and then exiting to the Internet?

Comment: @JohnRotenstein - Yes exactly! I cannot find anything in the AWS documentation that clarifies whether that is even possible. All the documentation points to setting up a separate IGW and/or NAT Gateway. Can that be done at all?

Comment: I have not done that, but I suspect you would need to edit the Route Tables on the Subnets to send traffic destined for `0.0.0.0/0` to the IP address of a router in your private network that can forward the traffic to the Internet. It's similar to setting the 'Gateway' configuration on a computer via DHCP.

Answer (score 0):

Is the subnet your EC2's are in routed through an Internet Gateway (IGW)? If you post one of your route tables as an example, could maybe provide some more directed feedback.

Comment: Thanks - I have added a diagram and route table to the post. Perhaps what I'm trying to do is not really possible. I was hoping to enable the private subnet EC2 instances to access the internet via my gateway and avoid having an AWS IGW or NAT Gateway.

Comment: Please phrase this as an explained conditional answer, in order to avoid the impression of asking a clarification question instead of answering (for which a comment should be used instead of an answer, compare https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead ). For example like "If your problem is ... then the solution is to .... because .... ."

Answer (score 0):

**If your EC2 Instance is in a Public subnet, you may want to check the following**

1. An Internet Gateway is attached to the VPC
2. A Route table is associated with the Subnet which is hosting the EC2.
3. The Route table should have an entry that sends traffic destined to internet `0.0.0.0` via `Internet Gateway`
4. The Instance is expected to have a Public IP address (Either via Subnet settings or Explicitly assigning one)

[image: Public Subnet]

**If your EC2 Instance is in a Private subnet, you may want to check the following**

- An Internet Gateway is attached to the VPC
- A NAT Gateway is created in a public subnet
- The NAT Gateway should have a public IP or Elastic IP address.
- A Route table associated with the public subnet

  - This directs traffic to internet `0.0.0.0` using `Internet Gateway`
- A Route table associated with the private Subnet (The Subnet that hosts the instance)

  - There should be an entry to direct traffic to NAT Gateway
- The Instance need not have a Public IP.

[image: Private Subnet]

Comment: Thanks - I have added a diagram and route table to the post. Perhaps what I'm trying to do is not possible. I was hoping to enable the private subnet EC2 instances to access the internet via my existing gateway (router) and avoid having a separate AWS IGW or NAT Gateway.

Answer (score 0):

You did it?
Today I was able to do it.

Simply edit your site-to-site connection configuration by adding 0.0.0.0/0 in the static routes.